# systemd: was the service stopped before `systemctl stop`?

Tags: systemd, systemctl

When I do `systemctl stop service` on a stopped or failed service, it returns 0 and no output. I need to know whether it was running before I call  this.

Calling `systemctl status` before stopping is not an option: it increases running time and introduces race conditions. Both reasons are important in my case.

Comment: I'm confused by your requirements; `stop` stops a service and `status` would tell you "whether it was running". Are you looking for a "stop only if it's already running" command? Or do you want "stop" to return different exit codes if the service was running and was successfully stopped? (In which case this may turn into a feature request of systemd)

Comment: I want `stop` to tell me what it has really done. A special exit code would be the best solution. Although a message in the output is acceptable too.

Answer (score 3):

If killing your service with a `TERM` signal is an appropriate way to stop it, you can use

```
systemctl kill --fail service
```

instead of

```
systemctl stop service
```

This will exit with code 0 if the service was running and killed, 1 if the service wasn’t running.

Comment: This might be a nice workaround. I'll check it!